# Openssl convert pem to crt with intermediate certificates

Tags: openssl

with Firefox it's easy to export the used SSL certificate of a page as x509 with all intermediate certificates as *.crt.

I'm in the need to do the same by converting *.pem files to *.crt as a non-binary format using openssl.

These are the current certs in use by apache:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert-start.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/key-no-pw.pem
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert-bundle.pem
```

I can easily convert the `SSLCertificateFile` to crt with:

```
openssl x509  -in cert-start.pem -out cert-start.crt
```

To build the crt with full chain I've tried `-chain`, `-clcerts` without luck.

What is the correct way for including all intermediate certificates from `SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert-bundle.pem`as well?

Comment: You mean this? `#cat domain.tld.key domain.tld.crt root.crt > domain.tld.pem`

Comment: `openssl x509  -in cert-start.pem -out cert-start.crt` does nothing (if no errors). `cert-start.crt` will have same content as `cert-start.pem`. `openssl` does not base its working on the filename. See documentation about `-inform` and `-outform`. But note that `.pem` and `.crt` extensions (or even `.cert`) are pure conventions, and mostly interchangeable. No respectable tool base its workings on this. `PEM` is a format (on how to store the content) and `crt` is just a human memoniker for `certificate`. Certificates can be encoded in PEM fornat, but other things can too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat cert-start.pem cert-bundle.pem > chain.pem
```

in case it would contain also the key (in some cases it is needed but depends on usage) ot would be

```
cat cert-start.pem cert-bundle.pem key-no-pw.pem > full_chain.pem
```

In case you would check the output you will see something like this (in case of chain.pem):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 ... <base64 encoded server cert> ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 ... <base64 encoded intermediate cert> ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And in case of of full_chain.pem it will be something like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 ... <base64 encoded server cert> ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 ... <base64 encoded intermediate cert> ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
 ... <base64 encoded key>
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

In case you would "check" it using `openssl x509 -in chain.pem` you will see just the first (in this case server) certificate. All the rest will be handled as comment - ignored. You have to separate it to extra file or just print specific line range via pipe to openssl to see the content. The real check can be done "visually" using cat or some text editor you prefer... Once the application expect pem / crt file this is what you need.

In case you would like to handle it as "container" the proper form is pkcs12. There you can handle it as set of certificates and handle it that way and see it / import it. The command would be in that case

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert-start.pem -inkey key-no-pw.pem -certfile cert-bundle.pem -out full_chain.p12 -nodes
```

The pkcs12 output can be checked using command

```
openssl pkcs12 -in full_chain.p12 -nodes
```

Please note that "correct" format (p12 or pem / crt) depends on usage.

Answer (score 3):

You simply concatenate them

```
cat domain.tld.key domain.tld.crt root.crt > domain.tld.pem
```

Comment: thanks. In my case, I this would read: `cat cert-bundle.pem cert-start.pem > domain.tld.pem` followed by `openssl x509  -in domain.tld.pem  -out out.crt` unfortunately this does not include the intermediate certs from cert-bundle.pem into out.crt. I think I miss something really obvious.